# How to implement a drag-and-drop Import-Function in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle12c

I am new to Oracle Apex and want to implement the following functionality:

A user of my webapplication should be able to drag and drop several *csv.files. By clicking the button "import" the content of those files should be inserted into several tables of my database. Each *.csv-file contains information for exactly one table.

I have found a dropzone-plugin on github (https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-dropzone) and added it to my page in Apex. If I am running my application I am currently able to drag and drop the files. The next step is to implement the functionality of my importer and I am really struggling with it. My first idea was to define a dynamic action for my import button but that didn't work so far. In the readme.md of the plugin I have read something about an apex_collection, but I don't really know how to use it.

Can you help me with that issue and tell me what steps I have to do next?

Here is a screenshot of how my drag and drop looks like:

[image]

Comment: Once you have loaded a file using the dropzone, you end up with a BLOB (binary large object) containing raw data. The next step is to interpret that data using a CSV parser, e.g. you could try CSV_UTIL_PKG from here: https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils

Comment: Ok this package is not bad. I managed to convert my file_blog into a .clob datatype, so my file-content is now a string. Does anyone know how to parse that string so I can get the information for each column, e.g.:

My clog-column contains the following information; "ryan;miller;agent;00567;" Now I want to store that information like that: ryan into surname-column, miller into name-column and so on..

So I need a function that can separate my string

Comment: Use CSV_UTIL_PKG, like I said...